# How to use custom attribute for price instead of 'price' for specific site?

Tags: attributes

Our Magento platform is connected to our product database. We're first building a wholesale site and want to display the price as the attribute "list_price" instead of the standard "price" which is our MSRP.

It's not a flat rule like a % off so I can't use the catalog pricing rules. Also we will be building out retail sites using the same catalog so I need to retain the "price" value to be used on different websites.

We have Magento's attributes synced to custom values in our DB using a staging table, so it seems most logical to somehow substitute 'price' for 'list_price' with this website only. I just don't see how to do that.

We could connect our "list_price" to an existing attribute in Magento if that would be easiest. Special_Price comes to mind but I just want it to display as the normal price and not as a special price.

Any ideas on the best way to do this? Thanks so much.
Here's the site btw: http://wholesale.navajomfg.com

Comment: This extension seems to be exactly what I'm working for but I don't think it's supported any longer: http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/Wildcardbi_RulePriceAttribute

Comment: group_price uses an array :

$product->setData('group_price',array (
    array (
        "website_id" => 3,
        "cust_group" => 4,
        "price" => 99

Could we configure the staging table to call list_price for the group_price price field? Website_ID for wholesale is 3. The issue is that we need it to work for both customer groups “General” and “NOT LOGGED IN” (1 and 0 respectively). 

Is it possible to use both cust_group 1 and 0 in the array, then generate array for all items in the DB so we can connect it to Magento, where it will use the group pricing across the wholesale site?

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use tierprices for that. You can apply the tierprice rule to a certain user group if you want, it'll give you some flexibility on what wholesale price you want to give to who. As far as displaying it as the normal price goes, it's easier to just do this with css and html than use custom attributes etc. This way price filtering etc will still work.